# How to add dynamic values to java new Object[] with different type of values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently using like below this syntax working fine

```
Object[] oParams = new Object[] {
    Integer.valueOf(this.userId),
    Date.valueOf(this.startDate), 
    Date.valueOf(this.endDate) 
};
jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, oParams);
```

if it is in `PHP` we can simply add with index but in java the following syntax is throwing error

```
oParams[3] = Integer.valueOf(this.userId)
```

If I add values like below,

```
List<Object> oParams = new ArrayList<Object>();
oParams.add(Integer.valueOf(this.userId));
oParams.add(Date.valueOf(this.startDate));
oParams.add(Date.valueOf(this.endDate));
jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, oParams);
```

It causing the following error,

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:949)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean that you want to extend the array, you can't. Arrays are fixed size. You can make a new bigger array and copy the contents into it. What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: If you want an extendable array, use a List. Arrays should be avoided in general.

Comment: i have to pass this object values into jdbc connection some cases i have to add parameters and values dynamic to the sql query. It's on subquery some values come from the parent class. i don't know how to combine all values to this.

Comment: @khelwood how to add different type of values in array or list. Java will accept the same type of values right?

Comment: You can put any kind of object in an `Object` array. But you can't write to an index after the end of the array. You can add any kind of object to a `List<Object>`.

Comment: When i use array list to `jdbcTemplate` it's throwing this error : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use. `Above syntax working fine`
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:949)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. if you really need an `Object[]` you could convert your `List<Object>` using [`.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()).

```
List<Object> oParams = new ArrayList<>();
oParams.add(Integer.valueOf(this.userId));
oParams.add(Date.valueOf(this.startDate));
oParams.add(Date.valueOf(this.endDate));
jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, oParams.toArray());
```